# RxJava2 - Chaining multiple observables with error messages

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am using RxJava2 to handle downloading some data using Retrofit2, saving it to the database, and showing an error message with an option to retry if something fails. If that is successful, I need to make another network request, handle the response, and present a different error message if that one failed. Once everything is finished, the user can continue on to the next screen.

I have had some success, but seem to not be able to get everything working at the same time. Either some of my tasks get skipped and the user jumps to the end of the chain, or the observables do not run sequentially.

Here is my latest attempt.

```java
Disposable disposable = initializeMySdk()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .andThen(checkStatus())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(userStatus -> downloadAppData())
            .flatMapCompletable((observable) ->
                    observable.flatMapCompletable((b) -> downloadUserData(getUserId())))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(() -> {
                startNextActivity();
            }, throwable -> Log.e(TAG, throwable.getMessage()));
```

`initializeMySdk()` returns a Completable.

`checkStatus()` returns Single.

`downloadAppData()` looks like this:

```java
private Observable<Object> downloadAppData() {
    return ApiUtils.downloadAppData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                mNoConnectionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            })
            .retryWhen(throwableObservable -> RxView.clicks(mRetryBtn))
            .flatMap(stringResponse -> handleNetworkResponse(stringResponse))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

`downloadUserData` is similar to `downloadAppData`, but instead of having a dialog with a "Retry" button, it is just a dialog that will let you continue. The is how it is working now, `downloadUserData` isn't getting called. Something seems funny with my `flatMapCompletable`s.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Here is what my block of code looks like now:

```java
 Disposable disposable = initializeMySdk()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .andThen(checkStatus())
            .flatMapCompletable(userStatus -> downloadAppData())
            .andThen(downloadUserData(getUserId()))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(() -> {
                startNextActivity();
            }, throwable -> Log.e(TAG, throwable.getMessage()));
```

Now the problem seems to be in my `retryWhen` line:

```
 .retryWhen(throwableObservable -> RxView.clicks(mRetryBtn))
```

I am getting this error message:

`Expected to be called on the main thread but was RxComputationThreadPool-1`

I have tried adding `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` in multiple places throughout my code without any luck. Removing the `retryWhen` seems to fix my problems, but I need the ability to retry.  `ApiUtils.downloadAppData()` is making a network request using Retrofit2, so that cannot run on the main thread.

If `ApiUtils.downloadAppData()` throws as error, I show an error screen to the user that has a `Retry` button, and that is the button that calls `retryWhen`. Why am I not able to run `ApiUtils.downloadAppData()` on the background thread, show my error screen and observe the `retryWhen` on the main thread, then retry `ApiUtils.downloadAppData()` on the background thread, and able to try this as many times as needed?

Comment: `downloadAppData()` returns `Observable`, so it wouldn't work inside `map()` operator. It should be used in `flatMap()`. Why not write `flatMap(userStatus -> downloadAppData()).flatMapCompletable(object -> downloadUserData(getUserId()))`?

Comment: @ConstOrVar Changing `map` to `flatMap` gives me this error: "Observable<Object> cannot be converted to SingleSource<? extends R>)"

Comment: As `checkStatus()` return `Single`, use [`Single.flatMapObservable()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flatMapObservable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-). flatMapObservable(userStatus -> downloadAppData()).flatMapCompletable(object -> downloadUserData(getUserId()))

Comment: Thanks @ConstOrVar. I've made some changes. Please take a look at my updated code.